# Division by 0 error in BigQuery even when short-circuiting should prevent it

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

In my data, the `fulfillment_ratio` field may or may not be equal to 0. I can't figure out why I am still getting division by 0 errors. I thought I was short-circuiting using an `IF` statement so that the calculation will not take place if a 0 exists for the given group.

```sql
SELECT
    order_key,
    order_source,
    sale_item.key AS key,
    ANY_VALUE(sale_item.name) AS name,
    ANY_VALUE(sale_item.sku) AS sku,
    ANY_VALUE(sale_item.quantity) * MIN(fulfillment_ratio) AS quantity_counted,
    MIN(sale_item.base_price) AS price,
    IF(COUNTIF(fulfillment_ratio = 0) > 0, 0, SUM(cogs / fulfillment_ratio) * MIN(fulfillment_ratio)) AS cost_of_goods_sold
  FROM 
    order_product_stockable_items
  GROUP BY
    order_key,
    order_source,
    sale_item.key
```

As you can see in the last line of the SELECT list, I'm counting to see if there are any cases where `fulfillment_ratio = 0`, if there are I was under the impression that `0` would be returned and the false condition would not be evaluated. However, I still get a division by 0 error. How is that possible? Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `NULLIF`:

```
COALESCE(SUM(cogs / NULLIF(fulfillment_ratio,0)) * MIN(fulfillment_ratio),0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. But do you have any idea why my method isn't working? The documentation says that the false condition is not evaluated if the expression is true. What am I missing?

Comment: @flyingL123 . . . There is not guarantee of short-circuiting with `if()`.  It should work with `case`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff the docs say: "If cond is true, returns true_result, else returns else_result. else_result is not evaluated if cond is true. true_result is not evaluated if cond is false or NULL. true_result and else_result must be coercible to a common supertype." AND "Conditional expressions impose constraints on the evaluation order of their inputs. In essence, they are evaluated left to right, with short-circuiting, and only evaluate the output value that was chosen."

Comment: Even with a case statement I get the same error. Is there some sort of issue with this `COUNTIF(fulfillment_ratio = 0) > 0`? Maybe it's not doing what I think it's doing?

Comment: Short circuiting won't work for some complex expressions. Try SAFE_DIVIDE.

Comment: @flyingL123 . . . It is a problem with the aggregation functions and optimization.  Elliott has the better answer.

Comment: WHAT? Is it a bug? How could the docs say it short circuits but then in practice we say it doesn't alway short circuit?